# Sending data to server using get request header

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, header, get-request

I use jQuery to contact my REST service on server side. The URL looks like this:

```
http://bla.com/?userid=1,2,3,4,5,6...
```

The userid string could be very long and it could happen that the max url size will be exceeded.
I can't do a post request, so my question is, whether it would be a good solution to send the userid data within the header? Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    headers:{'foo':'bar'},
    complete: function() {
        alert(this.headers.foo);
    }
});
```

Would this be possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can send header using Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken);
    },
    url: "entities",
    data: "json=" + escape(JSON.stringify(createRequestObject)),
    processData: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        $("#results").append("The result =" + StringifyPretty(msg));
    }
});
```

you can read more about header on [jQuery AJAX page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Also check this example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/2918/how-to-set-a-request-header-in-a-jquery-ajax-call.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain where i should put my userids in? Here: request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken); or here: data: "json=" + escape(JSON.stringify(createRequestObject)) ?

Comment: It depends on how you are going to process userid on server side, if you want to send it via header put it here like request.setRequestHeader("userid", 10); if on server side you are reading like $_GET['userid'] then add it in data

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible, alhough it would be advisable to just use POST, because it was meant to transfer lots of data.

Using headers is a workaround which results in the same results as POST; losing the ability to navigate forward and back without re-submitting (or re-sending headers in this case, will be impossible if the data is gone).

Comment: Thanks, problem is, we use JSONP. JSONP doesn't seem to work with post requests

Comment: Actually it is possible, altough it seems like a rather daunting task:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345493/using-put-post-delete-with-jsonp-and-jquery