# Post JSON data with $http.jsonp?

Tags: angularjs, json, jsonp

I am using AngularJS to make calls to a remote unit that supports JSON API. 
The call is proceeded as this:

```
'use strict';
var app=angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('Login', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.user;
        $scope.passwd = "";
        $scope.message = "";
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        $http.post('http://192.168.30.1/jsonrpc',
            {
                "params": [{
                    "url": "sys/login/user",
                    "data": [{
                        "passwd": $scope.passwd,
                        "user": $scope.user,
                    }]
                }],
                "session": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "method": "exec"
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.result.status.code == 0) {
                    $scope.message = 'Bienvenue'
                }
                else {
                    $scope.message = 'Non authetifie'
                }
            }, function () {
                $scope.message = 'erreur'
            })

    }
} );
```

As shown in the code above, The second argument in `$http.post` is some JSON data which will be sent to the remote unit and the response is also JSON.

When I send a request I can see the JSON response with fiddler but in the $scope.message I get `erreur` since for the javascript no response was received.

Since I am falling in the CORS problem, I want to know can I send this same data as JSONP using `$http.jsonp`?

The reason for my question is that `$http.jsonp` only takes the `url` and `[config]` as parameters unlike `$http.post` so I can't send my JSON data with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677773/my-client-side-cors-really-not-working-in-angular-controller-pls-help-me-tim

Comment: I don't think you can use jsonp like that. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call

Comment: Yep i admit deleted but  just posted documentations

Comment: Unless you control the API and can enable CORS you will need to use a proxy since jsonp does not support POST or request headers ... it is a script request

Comment: @charlietfl What is wrong with client side cors Post does it not worth a read ????

Comment: @N.V.Prasad all the documentation you're giving me says that using `$http.jsonp` only take the `url` as parameter. My question is how can I specify the json data to be sent in my request using this function?

Comment: @YacineBenSlimene you can't post period. Any data needs to be in a GET query string so you can pass params in `$http` config object. Also not all API's serve jsonp and you can't force it if they don't

Comment: @YacineBenSlimene - what is "the CORS problem" that you face? Is the remote unit under your control? Can you implement CORS?

Comment: @Starscream1984 The remote unit is a FortiOS equipment, so I can't enable CROS on it. By the way, when I send a request I can see the JSON response with fiddler but in the `$scope.message` I get erreur since for the javascript no response was received. I will add this remarque to the question. Sorry

Comment: @YacineBenSlimene - if enabling CORS is impossible, but you *can* configure the endpoint to serve JSONP - you'll have to also modify the endpoint to be a GET and pass all your data in the query string, as charlietfl suggests.

Comment: @Starscream1984 So I can't use `JSONP` to post data ? There is no way around this issue ?

Comment: @YacineBenSlimene - there is an answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345493/using-put-post-delete-with-jsonp-and-jquery that claims to achieve POST via JSONP. But I wouldn't like to try those complicated and unproven steps, it's much, much, much easier to change the endpoint to be a GET whilst you configure it to serve JSONP.

Comment: Can't you use a proxy that you do control?...that's usually the easiest workaround